# Configure Inetd settings for a particular FTP account

Tags: ftp, freebsd, inetd

Currently in Inetd , the protocol settings for a particular protocol is same for all the uses who are connecting to system using it . like FTP or so .

Is there a way to configure inetd to have a different settings for a particular user only ?

for example , currenlty in inetd:

> ftp stream tcp nowait/100/40/20   /usr/libexec/ftpd       ftpd -l -r
>   -W

Is there any way, to have configure new parameters ( nowait/300/50/40 for a particular FTP user only)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the inetd.conf line is for enabling FTP when needed, and it always uses that settings. It is a global setting.

So the answer is no.